# Justify Text in sIFR

Tags: sifr

G'day friends
i want to justify my text using sIFR, Whe i researched on that, i found that sIFR just have 3 options, textalign=center/left/right. But i wanna know how to justify the text..? is there any way i can use textalign=justify? when i use textalign=justify, it does not work.
Please help
Kind regards

Comment: You have three options.  That's it.

Comment: then how to justify text?, so there is no way i can justify text?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused about the meaning of justify. For typographical purposes, *align* and *justify* mean the same thing.

To justify text to the left;

```
textalign = left
```

To justify text to the right;

```
textalign = right
```

To justify text in the center;

```
textalign = center
```

**EDIT:**
I've just downloaded the latest nightly build of sIFR3 from [this link](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/Nightlies) and tested it out by editing the demo files provided. **text-align: justify** works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you Mat, please help me, justification for me is for the text, in which the text automatically becomes inline from right side. Like we can give text-justify value as "auto", newspaper etc in html. [text-align: justify;" align="center"] this is what is give in table to justify text. Its like, i can use JUSTIFY in word document to extend text in-line.

Comment: Ah I understand. I didn't even know text-align:justify existed until now (thanks)! If the sIFR docs don't mention it, you might be out of luck, as Josh Stodola said. You could always grab a copy and run a very quick test...

Comment: i tried but no luck, I wonder if some one have done it already, cuz while searching on internet, i found people crying for help with no luck so far. So can you please tell me any alternate way to do that?